# although logged in, no access to off line site, EE thinks I am not logged in

Tags: control-panel, cookies

Although I am logged in a s superadmin, I do not get access to a site that is offline. Klicking on the site name link, I get

```
To proceed to the URL you have requested, click the link below:

http://www.mysite.com/index.php
```

proceeding makes that I reach the offline status, as if I am not logged in. But I am!

When tampering with the url, I get acces, also a new window in same browsersession. This is of course not a desirable situation.

I studied all the posts I could find here about being kicked out of the site and or CP.

In the CP:
My cookie settings: all empty.
Securety settings: standard: (cookies and session for CP, cookies only for site.)

Help is much appreciated, I must solve this problem tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure the URL you logged in at and the URL you are trying to access the site is the same. like www or no www, etc.

Comment: Thank you. This is very tricky. EE sets, on install, the domainname as http:// I am used to full http: //www so confusion is eminent....